# charts.js tooltips on different data ranges

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js, momentjs

I'm using charts.js (with angular-charts directive), and I'm facing a problem with different dataset sizez. I have to display in a line-chart some values in a timeline. So my data is structured like this :

```
datasets : [
  [ {"x" : date1, "y" : 2 }, {"x" : date1, "y" : 5 } ..], //first dataset
  [ {"x" : date2, "y" : 3 }, {"x" : date4, "y" : 7 } ..] //second one
];
```

where date1, date2, .. date4 are moment dates, and y are random values. 
Now, if the first dataset has the same number of values of the second dataset, everything is okay. But if i have different dataset sizes (for example, the first one has values for yesterday, and today, the second one for today and tomorrow) then the legend tooltip is completely wrong. It always shows the NTH value of each series, even if they are in different dates. It's a little difficult to explain in words and english is not my language. I leave self-explaining screenshot here :

[image]

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it could be helpful for other developers, I've managed to solve the problem normalizing data. I.E. i've transformed my data from :

```
[ 
  [{"x" : date1, "y" : valueA }, {"x" : date2, "y" : valueB }, {"x" : date3, "y" : valueC }],
  [{"x" : date3, "y" : valueD }, {"x" : date4, "y" : valueE }]
]
```

to :

```
[ 
  [{"x" : date1, "y" : valueA }, {"x" : date2, "y" : valueB }, {"x" : date3, "y" : valueC }, {"x" : date4, "y" : undefined }],
  [{"x" : date1, "y" : undefined }, {"x" : date2, "y" : undefined },{"x" : date3, "y" : valueD }, {"x" : date4, "y" : valueE }]
]
```

So, each dataset contains the same number of tuples, that is the result of merging dates from the first dataset and the second one and removing duplicates.